# Is there a way to make a react js website work for mouse/touch if it wasn't written for mouse/touch initially?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking at some existing websites that have navigation via up/down/left/right/enter/escape and don't support touch. They don't use document.activeElement, which is the normal way for focus on html elements.

Is there a way to use the react API to directly focus and 'click' on react UI elements? Like a setstate call to the react UI DOM entry?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some examples or what you're working with / looking to do, it sounds like you are looking for [react refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).  These are special props you can use to access DOM elements directly, and manipulate them with operations like `focus`, or whatever else you need to do.  The documentation I linked has some examples using `focus`.